# PDO not reading nvarchar datatye of MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, nvarchar

I have one table in MSSQL Server 2012 whose data type of one column is defined as below:

```
COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME   COLUMN_SIZE
description   2005        nvarchar    1073741823
```

When I run this query:

```
select * from tablename
```

using PHP PDO then I don't get any result. And if I write names of all fields in above sql select query excluding this field then I am getting result.

What is wrong with this data type?

**Note:** this table is directly imported from MySQL by using some tool.

I have googled a lot but could not get any solution.

Comment: Maybe this is a similar issue and casting it would work? http://eugenioz.blogspot.com/2013/07/php-mssql-nvarchar-fetch-and-write-utf.html

Comment: It worked by using solution given at your suggested URL !!!

Comment: Great. You may want to post the solution from that link (or what you did) as an answer to so others that find this thread can resolve their issues as well.

Comment: It would be great if you post that solution as an answer and i would like to upvote and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution on this website seems relevant here, http://eugenioz.blogspot.com/2013/07/php-mssql-nvarchar-fetch-and-write-utf.html.

In case that site removes the post or goes down the solution is to cast the nvarchar as a varchar.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([field] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS field FROM table
```

For insertion it is showing it as

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_nvarchar_field)  VALUES(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), 0x'.$value.'))
```